# shuffle list with repetition constraint 2-back python

Tags: python, shuffle

I have the following list:

```
a=['airplane','track','car','train']
```

I would like to create a list that presents every item of this list twice, but prevents item repetitions for the next two rows. That means airplane can only appear after airplane as long as 2 different items are in between so b would be a good candidate:

```
b=['airplane','track','car','airplane','train','track','car' etc.]
```

but c would not:

```
c=['airplane,'track','airplane', etc.]
```

I was thinking of some kind of bruteforce operation where:
1. a is duplicated
2. random.shuffle(a)
3. test for repetition (maybe something like below:

```
curWord[n]==curWord[n+1]
```

4. Re-shuffle if `TRUE` and start over. (I don't actually know what the command would be to instruct python to read the truth value. I imagine an `if` statement will work, but in the case of a `FALSE` I don't know how I'd instruct python to carry on

In any case, although getting answers to the particular questions above would be good for my own knowledge, I can see that the implementation I have considered would probably take really long as the list increases.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need some list with two copies of each element, is there a reason why this won't work for when the original list is longer than 2 elements?

```
In [138]: a=['airplane','track','car','train']

In [139]: a + a
Out[139]: ['airplane', 'track', 'car', 'train', 'airplane', 'track', 'car', 'train']
```

If you are asking the more abstract question of, "How do I sample from the space of permutations of my list elements such that they don't appear within two elements of an identical element" then the following should work.

Note that getting some structure where the elements appear twice is as easy as `a + a` and then you can worry about restricting the permutations of `a + a` -- no need to overthink the "how do I get two of each" part of the problem.

```
import random

def valid_duplicate_spacing(x):
    for i, elem in enumerate(x):
        if elem in x[i+1:i+3]:
            return False
    return True

def sample_permutations_with_duplicate_spacing(seq):
    sample_seq = seq + seq                 
    random.shuffle(sample_seq)    
    while not valid_duplicate_spacing(sample_seq):
        random.shuffle(sample_seq)

    return sample_seq
```

Then this can be used as follows:

```
In [165]: sample_permutations_with_duplicate_spacing(a)
Out[165]: ['airplane', 'train', 'track', 'car', 'train', 'track', 'car', 'airplane']

In [166]: sample_permutations_with_duplicate_spacing(a)
Out[166]: ['train', 'airplane', 'car', 'track', 'train', 'airplane', 'track', 'car']
```

If you're talking about merely randomly sampling from the list, such that a sample is not replaced for the two following draws, you could use a generator:

```
import random 

def draw_with_delayed_replacement(seq):
    drawn = random.choice(seq)
    rejectables = [drawn]
    yield drawn

    drawn = random.choice(seq)
    while drawn in rejectables:
        drawn = random.choice(seq)
    rejectables.append(drawn)
    yield drawn

    while True:
        drawn = random.choice(seq)
        if drawn in rejectables:
            continue
        else:
            rejectables.pop(0)
            rejectables.append(drawn)
            yield drawn
```

Then you can do the following:

```
In [146]: foo = draw_with_delayed_replacement(a)

In [147]: foo.next()
Out[147]: 'car'

In [148]: foo.next()
Out[148]: 'train'

In [149]: foo.next()
Out[149]: 'track'

In [150]: foo.next()
Out[150]: 'car'

In [151]: foo.next()
Out[151]: 'train'

In [152]: foo.next()
Out[152]: 'track'

In [153]: foo.next()
Out[153]: 'car'

In [154]: foo.next()
Out[154]: 'airplane'

In [155]: foo.next()
Out[155]: 'track'

In [156]: foo.next()
Out[156]: 'train'
```

However, in this case you can't guarantee you're going to get a sample where each element appears exactly twice, and this may be inefficient for small lists.

Comment: thanks very much. Solution 1 is exactly what I needed to do. Great explanations by the way. It all makes perfect sense. Solution 2 is fun though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, which does not guarantee that every token appears exactly n times, though.

One could easily extend my solution to guarantee that, but that would result in a possible deadlock scenario which one would have to check for then.

```
>>> def magicsequence(tokens, length):
...   sequence = []
...   while len(sequence) < length:
...     candidate = random.choice(tokens)
...     if candidate not in sequence[-2:]:
...        sequence.append(candidate)
...   return sequence
```

Comment: If you set `foo = tokens + tokens` and then draw `candidate` from `foo`, with a step to remove one copy of `candidate` from `foo` whenever it succeeds in the `if` statement's `append` step, then this would guarantee the every-element-appears-twice property. However, at that point it would just be a less efficient implementation than using `random.shuffle`, due to the repeated calls to `random.choice`.

Comment: Yes, and there whould be a chance of deadlock: when there is only ["airplane","airplane"] left, for example.

Comment: @ch3ka thanks for your suggestions too. Very helpful too! Especially in light of your discussion with EMS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that satisfies the constraints and always returns a list with each element twice. It runs in O(n^2) time, where n is the length of the list.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations
from random import choice, shuffle

def shuffle_with_constraints(x):
    if len(x) < 3:
        raise ValueError("Lists with length less than 3 have no valid shuffles")

    output = []
    #a counter representing how many times we still need to insert an element
    available = Counter(x*2)
    while available:

        if len(output) == len(x)*2-6: #we just need to insert six elements
            distinct = len(available) #how many distinct elements we need to insert

            if distinct == 6:
                pass #there is no problem
            elif distinct == 3: #only six possibilities
                end = list(available)
                shuffle(end)
                return output + end*2
            else:
                #enumerate all 720 permutations and select a valid one
                possibles = [possible for possible in permutations(available.elements())
                             if valid_6_shuffle(possible)]
                return output+list(choice(possibles))

        #choose a valid element and append it to the output
        next = choice(list(set(available)-set(output[-2:])))
        output.append(next)

        #remove it from the availables
        if available[next] == 2:
            available[next] -= 1
        else:
            del available[next]

    return output

def valid_6_shuffle(x):
    for a,b,c in zip(x,x[1:],x[2:]):
        if a==b or b==c or a==c:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: It's possible to write a solution that does this in O(n) time.

Comment: @senderle Do you mind explaining how to do this in O(n) time?

Comment: Well -- I'm pretty sure you can. I wrote a version that works with the original settings (2 duplicates of each item and a gap of 2) but I couldn't get it to work with higher values, so there's actually something wrong. I didn't have time to debug so I didn't post it.

Comment: The idea is that you use a modified [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) that also keeps track of the end of the list. When you select an "illegal" value, move it to the end of the list, and move the pointer to the end down by one. When they meet, you'll have a mostly-shuffled list, and a few rogue values at the end. Then find appropriate places to insert those. The odds of there being very many rogue values actually goes down as the list gets larger, so I'm pretty sure it's average case O(n).